# Compare long strings and return similarity with a percentage

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm working on a function that gets two strings and compares them letter by letter. I'm not asking for the logic to write into this kind of funciton, but I'd like to know if there is already an existing function that does just that.

The function gets two strings and returns a percentage value (between 0 and 100) to represent how much these two strings are similar.

For example:

```
String 1: "ABCDEFG"
String 2: "HIJKLMN"
----------
result: 0%

String 1: "ABCDEFG"
String 2: "ABCDEFG"
----------
result: 100%
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is! It's called Levenshtein distance! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance. You can use this algorithm (You should be able to find an implemented levenshtein distance algorithm in most languages) and extend it so you get an int return value which represents the similarity in percentage.

Comment: Exactly, and you can get an implementation of this algorithm in many languages including SQL functions.